# WSO2IS - Upgrading PasswordDigest property for existing deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We intend to change the digest properties of our user-mgt.xml file to make changes to how our passwords are stored (WSO2IS 5.3.0)

```
...
            <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA</Property>
            <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">false</Property> 
...
```

I'm curious if WSO2IS will automatically handle upgrading existing users, or if I need to follow a process similar to the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971316/want-to-convert-a-website-password-encryption-from-sha1-to-sha256).

EDIT: I will also note that we are going to start salting passwords as well. So far my approach (again, assuming that wso2 does not automatically handle this), will be to add a new local authenticator that will come before the basic authenticator to update passwords without salts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a custom local authenticator may not be the best solution for you but you have below options for given requirement.

- Configure secondary user store with new PasswordDigest,
  passwordHashMethod values. New users need to be added to secondary
  user store. During the authentication old users will be authenticated
  against Primary user store and new users will be authenticated
  against Secondary user store.

*Please note PasswordDigest will be
   affected in JDBC user store and passwordHashMethod will be affected
   on LDAP user store.*

- For old users you can initiate forget password or password recovery
  flow due to authentication failure
- In case of you are using JDBC user store manager you can write simple
  program to retrieve old password and restore them with new
  encryption. (Table UM_USER column UM_USER_PASSWORD in store DB)

Comment: Thanks for presenting multiple solutions (we are using the JDBCUserStoreManager). Responding to each solution individually:

1) To be clear, new users would be the only ones with our updated password digest? Old users would still have the outdated one?
2) I would like to avoid this solution (due to it offloading the issue onto the user), though this would definitely be the easiest 
3) This solution seems promising, though I don't understand how we'd recover the plaintext password (since SHA1 is one way) in order to re-hash it. If you could elaborate on this one, that'd be awesome

Comment: Also, for the custom local authenticator approach, see the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395783/wso2-add-local-authentication-step-before-basic-auth) . In theory it will work, but I am running into the issue mentioned there

Comment: I also realized another option could be to add a class that extends AbstractIdentityUserOperationEventListener which could update credentials on doPreAuthenticate, let me know what you think about that as well

Comment: 1) yes your understanding is correct 2) Avoided 3) yes your point is correct i was thinking certificate base encryption I will correct the answer. Yes doPreAuthenticate also a possible option too but how can you identify updated password digest and old password digest ? and you may need to handle the situation user try with invalid password

Comment: I think the preAuthenticate approach would have to try authentication with the old digest first (avoiding re-calling the preAuth method and infiinitely looping...) before updating to the new one. Typing that out makes it seem like a less desirable solution

I have accepted your answer since you've given a technically viable solution (the second one). I will end up proceeding with either the preAuth approach or the custom authenticator approach

Comment: I would suggest you to go with preAuth approach and let me know if you need any code level support